# Почему рэп читают?

Tags: этимология, заимствования, лексическая-сочетаемость, идиомы

По-русски мы говорим:

> Этот парень классно читает рэп!

или даже:

> Как классно зачитал этот парень!

Но почему так сложилось, что рэп именно читается?

В английском, откуда, вероятно, и пришло это слово рэп вполне успешно «рэпится» (*rap* 'рэп-музыка' и *to rap* 'читать рэп'). Более официально — *to perform rap music* 'исполнять рэп-музыку'. Ни о каком «чтении» речи не идет.

Answer (score 5):

Нам будет достаточно [Большого толкового словаря](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2&all=x), поясняющего, что такое говорение нараспев **в русском языке** англичанина рэпа (помета: англицизм):

**РЕЧИТАТИВ,** -а; ***м.*** [итал. *recitatio* от *recitare* - декламировать] *Муз.* Вокальная форма, воспроизводящая в пении интонацию и ритмику речи, используемая обычно в опере. *Мастер речитатива*. **<Речитативом**, *в зн. нареч.* *Говорить, читать р.* (нараспев). *Речитативный стиль. Речитативная мелодия.*

**[РЭП,](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BF)** -а; ***м.*** [англ. *rap* - слегка ударять] **1.** Декламация, речитативное исполнение стихов под ритмическую музыку. *Читать рэп. Исполнять рэп на чьи-л. стихи.* **2.** Танец под такую музыку. *Танцевать рэп.* □ ***неизм. в зн. прил.*** *Стиль рэп. Танец рэп.*

---

[**Рэп**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8D%D0%BF) (англ. *rap, rapping*) — ритмичный речитатив, обычно читающийся под бит. Бит — доля *(в музыке)* (арх. *время такта*; англиц. *бит*, англ. *beat*) — элементарная единица музыкального метра. За эту единицу чаще всего принимается 1 четвертная нота.

Answer (score 0):

Словарь разрешает как *читать*, так и *исполнять* рэп, в Нацкорпусе преобладает "читать рэп" (нашлось только 4 вхождения "исполнять рэп", да и то в газетном копрусе). Очевидно, люди видят в рэпе в первую очередь стихи, хотя в моем восприятии это отдельный жанр и именно слово "исполнять" отражает его суть.